# How to Fix Common Image Issues in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am learning to develop WordPress theme and I am unable to find out how to align images, resize or crop them, or display them in a gallery format.

Comment: Hi, could you provide code or something to reproduce or more infos. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Image Alignment

CSS handles the alignments of images. When a user uploads an image and selects how their image will be aligned, WordPress simply adds a class based on the user's selected alignment (e.g. alignleft, alignright, aligncenter, etc.)

A complete list of such WordPress generated classes can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes) in WordPress codex.

## Resize and Crop

It is recommended to use the default image sizes and manipulate the images with CSS, so that the site doesn't generate additional images unnecessarily and thus increase the size of the WordPress folders.

However, if you do need to resize or crop images when they're uploaded, as a theme developer, you can use the add_image_size() function in your theme's ***functions.php*** file.

Here are the parameters that this function takes:

```php
add_image_size( string $name, int $width, int $height, bool|array $crop = false )
```

Here's an example use of the function:

```php
add_image_size( 'custom-size-name', 440, 360 );
```

To do a hard vs soft crop, you can add a fourth (boolean true/false) parameter in the add_image_size() function.

For example, to do a hard crop:

```php
add_image_size( 'custom-size-name', 440, 360, true );
```

Read more about this in [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#crop-mode)

To use these sizes of post thumbnails, you can do this (inside a loop):

```php
the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'custom-size-name' );
```

or this (outside a loop)

```php
the_post_thumbnail( '123', 'custom-size-name' ); 
// here 123 is the ID of the post, which has the thumbnail.
```

## Gallery

To show the images in a gallery format, you either need to create a custom gallery view using css and js (or use one of the gallery css/js plugins), or use the default WordPress [gallery shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode).

An example usage of the shortcode in the WYSIWYG editor or the block editor (or even page builders)

```
[gallery ids="123,345,456,567"]
```

*The ids used in the gallery shortcode refer to the ids of the images, not the posts they're related to (whether they are connected to any post or not).*

To use the gallery shortcode in a .php file, use the [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function:

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="123,345,456,567"]'); ?>
```

Comment: @neerajas I'm glad that I could help. If you like the answer, please select it as the correct answer and upvote it, please. Thank you.